# ggplot geom_rect color gradient (without reference to data)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if it is possible to have a geom_rect with a color gradient without a data reference, i.e. outside of aes().
I would like the two rectangles in the bottom of the following plot to show a color gradient from red to white (left to right) and the top one to show a color gradient from yellow to white.
Is this possible in a simple way or do I have to create data to refer to?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = c(1, 3), xmax = c(2.5, 4), ymin = c(1, 1), ymax = c(2, 2)), color = "black", fill = "red") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 3, ymax = 4), color = "black", fill = "yellow") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

I tried to use `scale_fill_gradient` with `geom_tile` but this doesn't really do what I want: 1. the two supposed-to-be-red rectangles share a gradient and don't start with pure red each and 2. I can't manage to use two different `scale_fill_gradient`'s in one plot.

```
foo <- tibble(x = seq(from = 1, to = 2.5, by = 0.001),
              y = rep(1, 1501))
bar <- tibble(x = seq(from = 3, to = 4, by = 0.001),
              y = rep(1, 1001))
foobar <- tibble(x = seq(from = 1, to = 3.5, by = 0.001),
              y = rep(3, 2501))

ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  geom_tile(data = bar, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'red', high = 'white') +
  geom_tile(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'yellow', high = 'white') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the function `new_scale_fill` from `ggnewscale` between your two different `scale_fill_gradient` functions in your plot process. This will reset your aesthetics to make it possible to use another gradient like this:

```r
library(tibble)
foo <- tibble(x = seq(from = 1, to = 2.5, by = 0.001),
              y = rep(1, 1501))
bar <- tibble(x = seq(from = 3, to = 4, by = 0.001),
              y = rep(1, 1001))
foobar <- tibble(x = seq(from = 1, to = 3.5, by = 0.001),
                 y = rep(3, 2501))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  geom_tile(data = bar, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'red', high = 'white') +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'yellow', high = 'white') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To add for each `geom_tile` a gradient color, you could use for each tile `new_scale_fill` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'red', high = 'white', guide = 'none') +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = bar, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'red', high = 'white') +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'yellow', high = 'white') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This solves one of my problems, but is it possible for **both** red boxes to start from 'pure' red and end with 'pure' white?

Comment: Hi @Rumpl, See my updated answer!